# Bootstrap dropdown cut off behined scrollable container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am facing an Issue with Bootstrap Drop Down. My dropdown is inside a scrollable `div` with fix height.

When I click on the dropdown, menu appears behind the scroll content. While normal `select` works perfectly fine.

[image]

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb6LLj2b/) which demonstrates the issue I am facing.

I tried by applying `position: fixed` to `.dropdown-menu` class but that is also not working.

Is there any work around without using JQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

As the drop-down has CSS `position: absolute` and it is under a container which has CSS `position: relative`.
Thus solution is difficult(but possible) using `z-index`.

However, solution would be easy using `position: fixed` with proper calculations of its parent's `top offset` value.

```
$('.btn-group .dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    var topPos = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':topPos, 'left':'auto'});
})
```

Check out modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/sb6LLj2b/7/).

**Soution 2- (If you can edit HTML of source)**

Easiest would be to modify the source HTML like below

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option selected>Default</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/sb6LLj2b/8/)

Answer (score 0):

hello brother as samir bhosle mentioned how to use the select but my question is what kind of css you want to put on the options which are not working on bootstrap while i tried somthing which might help you check this fiddle[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb6LLj2b/1/)

```
    <select type="button" class="btn btn-default">
       <option class="text-success">1</option>
       <option class="text-danger">2</option>
       <option class="text-primary">3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
       <option>6</option>
       <option>7</option>
     </select><br>
```

this is what i did and its working fine

Comment: I cannot apply padding on option. That is the reason why I decided to choose `bootstrap `

Comment: This is the same which you mentioned in your answer

Comment: you didnt see the lil bit of padding in it [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb6LLj2b/4/)

Comment: No I don't see any padding. I am checking in IE11 and Chrome

Answer (score -1):

You are using bootstrap dropdown.
What you need is bootstrap select.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="xyz">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: see the image I have attached

Comment: In `Bootstrap Select` I cannot apply CSS to `option` element

Comment: Use this if you want to style the options:
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/