# JQuery Offset issue when div position is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which has a page layout and style something like mentioned in this [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fahcmd1m/)

Now Using JQuery when I click on the button, content is being displayed properly as shown below:

[image]

But when I first scroll the page and then click the button, content is not displaying properly as shown:

[image]

Can you please guide me to handle this situation ?

I have used below jQuery for this. But it seems `offset` or `position` is not working

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var t = $(this).offset();
  console.log(t);
  $('.control-container').css('top', t.top + 20 + 'px');
  $('.control-container').css('display', 'block');
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
$('.control-container').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: check out my answer... 2 examples of how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `offset` to achieve that... And if you need to keep `CSS` with `position:fixed`, you need to switch it in `javascript` to `static`.

The thing you are looking for is simply `display:table` ...

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.control-container').css({'display': 'table','position': 'static'});
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
   $('.control-container').css({'display': 'none','position': 'fixed'});
});
```

[Check out this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fahcmd1m/3/)

---

But if you really need a solution with `position:fixed` based on `button` position, you should try this way:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var button_fixed_position = $('#btn').get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
  $('.control-container').css({'display': 'block','left' : button_fixed_position.left, 'top' : button_fixed_position.bottom});
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
   $('.control-container').css({'display': 'none'});
});
```

[Check out second JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fahcmd1m/4/)

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` works perfectly. Is there any performance impact if I use `getBoundingClientRect()` ?

Comment: shouldn't impact the performance ... not that it would be visible any way

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to specifically mention `position` property here.

Also remove the closing `a` tag and replace it with `</button>`

Currently container is occupying full width ,but that can also be set

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var t = $(this).offset();
  console.log(t);
  $('.control-container').css('top', t.top + 30 + 'px');
  $('.control-container').css('display', 'block');
});

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  $('.control-container').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: maroon;
  color: #fafafa;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-size: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 60px;
}

.control-container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  #position: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both">

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
    <div class="control-container" style="display:none;">
      Keep me exactly underneath 'Click Me' when Page is scrolled.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is right. But I cannot change the layout or css of the website. (Of course replacing closing anchor with button, that was a typo :) ). There will be a huge impact if i change.

Comment: You mean you can't remove `positon:fixed` ?

Comment: @FlashThunder: Yes

Answer (score 1):

CSS position `fixed` property positions an element referencing view's/body's dimension.

If you have access of modifying `CSS`, then just remove the `position: fixed;` property from `.control-container`.

If you don't have access, then using script add `position: static !important` property to `.control-container`.

```
$('.control-container').css('cssText', 'position: static !important');
```

Modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/fahcmd1m/5/)

Comment: I mentioned that I could not change the `CSS`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that comment. This is why I have also mentioned second solution with `$('.control-container').css('cssText', 'position: static !important');`. Just one line, and you can **remove** `$('.control-container').css('top', t.top + 30 + 'px');`. Enjoy :)

Comment: I cannot change `postion: static` because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094632/bootstrap-dropdown-cut-off-behined-scrollable-container issue.